# How to fill blank cells with the value above (and not get referencing error when deleting)

Tags: excel, vba

In column A of my data, I have the country to which a particular project belongs to: For example: NZ. Column B would list: Type of Project. column C would have: Project Code. Column D would have name of project.

I Have about 11 types of projects. My existing code can fill down column A and B with the correct country And project type.

However, if I need to delete some types of projects(for e.g software,others,operations..etc) after the code is run, I would get a cell referencing error. This would cause the country name in column A to have cell referencing error for the rest of the remaining types of projects.

Thus, I need a code tat would not get me a referencing error and even when I delete the 1st type of project(software).

My existing code is as follows:

```
Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range ("A7 : B" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:xlNone, _ SkipBlanks:=False,Transpose:=False
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellsTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 ="=R[-1]C"
```

Comment: Why don't you just paste values after setting the formula?

Comment: I need to run a macro that auto fill down column A and B with a click of a button. My boss does not want to have to do it manually. (Sorry,I din quite get your question)

Answer (score 0):

I think what Wyatt Shipman was saying was add the paste values to your macro...
Here's the full code now, but you had a typo in your OP.  It should be xlCellTypeBlanks not xlCellsTypeBlanks.

```
Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A7 : B" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

With Range("A7:B" & Lastrow)
    .Cells.Copy
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).Select
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was getting at.

Comment: Hi, thank u for the reply! However, when I run the code, I get a run time error 1004 that says method 'Range of Object'_Global'failed. Apparently the error is with the first line of the code. Any idea why? (Sorry guys, im new to this)

Comment: I updated it to fix your typo of xlCellTypeBlanks in the post, which is what caused the 1004.

Comment: Thank u! Tat really helped alot!